# Issue with the control m characters in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle and i want to see whether do i have any control "m" characters in that table how can i see that  any one has a query to view them.

Thank you

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific if you want a good answer. Are you checking all the columns in the table for "m"? What do you want for a result of your query? All the records containing "m" in any of the columns? If you provide your table structure and sample data you will get a better response.

Comment: Yes sir i need to check all the columns whether do they contain control M characters in a table @JacobH how do i conform the respective column have control M characters or not.?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the columns"? Do you expect to find CTRL-M characters in columns that are NUMBER of DATE data type? That doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the row which have them in a particular column using `LIKE`:

```
select * from your_table where col like '%' || chr(13) || '%';
```

According to http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html the `^M` is ASCII 13 and hence the `CHR(13)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DUMP()` to see control characters:

```
SELECT col1, DUMP(col1,17)
FROM  table
WHERE DUMP(col1,17) LIKE '%^%' --Optional; filters to only results with control characters
```

`17` is used to display results as single characters.